# How to output an array into a table with 2 column in row

Tags: php

Below is my code

```
 $itemSpec = Array
(
    [0] => Brand:Adidas
    [1] => Style:Snowsuits & Bibs
    [2] => Country:China
    [3] => Material:Cotton Blend
    [4] => Sport:Bowling 
    [5] => Sleeve length:Short Sleeve
    [6] => Theme:Liverpool
)
```

The above array value is a combination of title and value of item specification separated by:

```
foreach ($itemSpec as $v){
     $allItemSpec = explode(':', $v);

     if($allItemSpec[0] == "Country"){
     $allItemSpec[0] = "Country/Region of 
       Manufacture";
       }
      $allItemSpec = "<tr>"
       "<td>$allItemSpec[0]:</td>
      <td>$allItemSpec[1]</td>
        </tr>";
       echo $allItemSpec;
      }
```

Below is the image of what i wanted to acheive

WHAT I WANTED TO ACHIEVE
[image]

THE BELOW IS THE CURRENT RESULT I'M HAVING
[image]

[image]

I want to have only 4 td in a tr, and if I remove 2 td from within the code what I get is only 2 td within a tr which is not the result I want, I hope someone can help with this and thanks in advance.

Comment: the current result is not what the code is doing. Also use ['key' => 'value'] instead of explode. Please send the actual current code

Comment: Thanks for your reply i will edit and explain in more details

Comment: @ Friedrich Roell  i edited my question and i changed the second image which is the actual result i'm getting from the code above, array $itemspec as you can see above is an index array and the value is a string separated by : sign, now i want to get the string on the left of the : sign as the title and the string on the right as the value so i used explode, which gives me desire result, now i need to output the result in a table and i need to output only 2 on a tr so if i have 7 in the array it means i need 4 tr with one of it only having on td, but in my result i got 7 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">

    .container { width: 1000px; float: left; }
    .container .item { width: 50%; float: left; height: 50px; }

</style>

<?php


$itemSpec = Array
(
    0 => "Brand:Adidas",
    1 => "Style:Snowsuits & Bibs",
    2 => "Country:China",
    3 => "Material:Cotton Blend",
    4 => "Sport:Bowling", 
    5 => "Sleeve length:Short Sleeve",
    6 => "Theme:Liverpool"
);



echo '<div class="container">';

foreach ( $itemSpec as $v ) {

    $allItemSpec = explode(':', $v);

    if( $allItemSpec[0] == "Country" ) {

        $allItemSpec[0] = "Country/Region of Manufacture";

    }


     echo '<div class="item">' .$allItemSpec[0]. ":" .$allItemSpec[1] . '</div>';

}

echo '</div>';

?>
```

Comment: thanks for your replay i got excatly the same result as yours so maybe what i needed is the css styling to put say for instance Brand:  Adidas and Style:  Snowsuits & Bibs on the same row, please can you help me with the css, thanks